# SQL update scalar function

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, sql-update, sql-execution-plan

When I run this query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET x = (SELECT round(random()*100));
```

All records have the same value for `x`. This makes sense.

When I run this query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET x = round(random()*100);
```

It updates all records in the table and for each record the value of `x` is different.

I would like to know whats happening in the background for the second query. Is it running a update query for each record id(1....n)?

I am guessing it works similar to triggers, where for each row before updating

1. the trigger intercepts
2. calls the function and sets value of x
3. executes query

What is actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather simple, really. The function `random()` is defined `VOLATILE`.

If you put it into a subquery, you generate a derived table with a single row. Postgres can materialize the result and reuse it in the outer query many times.

Otherwise Postgres calls the function for every row. That's how `VOLATILE` functions have to be treated. [Per documentation on **function volatility**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-volatility.html):

> A `VOLATILE` function can do anything, including modifying the database.
>   It can return different results on successive calls with the same
>   arguments. The optimizer makes no assumptions about the behavior of
>   such functions. **A query using a volatile function will re-evaluate the
>   function at every row** where its value is needed.

Bold emphasis mine.